# How to make Pylance and Pydantic understand each other when instantiating BaseModel class from external data?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic, pylance

I am trying to instantiate `user = User(**external_data)`, where `User` is Pydantic `BaseModel`, but I am getting error from Pylance, which don't like my `external_data` dictionary and unable to figure out that data in the dict is actually correct (see first screenshot).

[image: Type error]

I found a workaround by creating `TypedDict` with the same declaration as for `User(BaseModel)`. Now Pylance is happy, but I am not, because I need to repeat myself (see second screenshot).

[image: Repetition]

Any ideas on how to make Pylance and Pydantic understand each other without repetition?

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypedDict

class UserDict(TypedDict, total=False):
    id: int
    name: str
    signup_ts: datetime
    friends: list[int]


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = "John Doe"
    signup_ts: datetime | None = None
    friends: list[int] = []


external_data: UserDict = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Vlad',
    'signup_ts': datetime.now(),
    'friends': [1, 2, 3],
}

user = User(**external_data)
print(user)
print(user.id)
```

Pylance error for the case with no `UserDict`:

```
Argument of type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "id" of type "int" in function "__init__"
  Type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to type "int"
    "datetime" is incompatible with "int"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
Argument of type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "name" of type "str" in function "__init__"
  Type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to type "str"
    "datetime" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
Argument of type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "signup_ts" of type "datetime | None" in function "__init__"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
Argument of type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "friends" of type "list[int]" in function "__init__"
  Type "int | str | datetime | list[int]" cannot be assigned to type "list[int]"
    "datetime" is incompatible with "list[int]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) external_data: dict[str, int | str | datetime | list[int]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why the errors?

These warnings are to be expected because the type of your `external_data` object (without using a `TypedDict`) will be inferred by Pylance as `dict[str, U]`, where `U` is the **union** of all the types it sees in the **dictionary values**. In your example `U = int | str | datetime | list[int]`.

Normal dictionaries are **homogeneous** in their key type as well is their value type and thus have no way to distinguish types between items. This means that *every* key of `external_data` will be seen as a `str` (which is fine) and *every* value will be seen as `int | str | datetime | list[int]`.

Since your Pylance is configured to expect *distinct* types for the keyword arguments passed to the model's `__init__` method, this causes a problem. It sees that you are unpacking a dictionary, where the values are all of the aforementioned union type, yet for example the `id` argument must be of type `int` and of course `int | str | datetime | list[int]` is not a subtype of `int`. Same for all the other `__init__` parameters.

### `TypedDict` (sort of) works

The main difference between a normal `dict` and a `TypedDict` is that the latter can distinguish (value) types between items. But the drawback in this case is the repetition of course.

Since `TypedDict` is a construct that exists *solely* for the benefit of static type checkers like Pylance, it would make no sense to somehow "dynamically" construct it from the field definitions of a model, even though that may get rid of the repetition.

The other way around, i.e. construct a model class from a `TypedDict`, is possible, but has the reverse problem. A type checker will have no way to infer the model members and their types.

### Workarounds

Since you are not using the keyword-argument syntax directly anyway, but constructing a dictionary first, there is really no need to rely on those keyword-argument type checks at all. If you needed/wanted that additional type safety, you would simply initialize the model as `User(id=123, ....)`.

Therefore I see essentially two ways around your issue:

1. Use a `type: ignore` directive.
2. Use an alternative constructor.

The first is easy. Simply put a `# type: ignore` comment next to the constructor call. The second is different depending on the major version of Pydantic you are using, and it is what I usually do in that situation.

##### Pydantic `1.x`

You have the [`BaseModel.parse_obj`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#helper-functions) method for this purpose:

> **`parse_obj`**: this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model, except it takes a `dict` rather than keyword arguments.

```py
...
external_data = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Vlad',
    # ...
}
user = User.parse_obj(external_data)
```

##### Pydantic `2.x`

You have the [`BaseModel.model_validate`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.1/usage/models/#helper-functions) for this purpose:

> **`model_validate`**: this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model, except it takes a `dict` rather than keyword arguments.

```py
...
external_data = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Vlad',
    # ...
}
user = User.model_validate(external_data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `parse_obj` is quite happy with this 
```
external_data = {
    'id': 'foo', 'name': 'Vlad', 'signup_ts': datetime.now(), 'friends': [1, 2, 3],
}
user = User.parse_obj(external_data)
```
Notice, id is a string. I understand that auto inferred type is vague, that's why I created workaround with `TypeDict`. This is erratic behavior to my taste - all the data is there. TypeScript for example able to handle situations similar to this. 
I think either:
1. `TypeDict` must be auto inferred by default
2. There must be a way to force 1. if it can not be default (compatibility)

Comment: @VladAnkudinov This is not TypeScript. Python is a dynamically typed language and the typing system is a patchy and imperfect layer on top. As I said, if you want the additional type safety, don't use a dictionary. Instantiate the object properly. If you _do_ use a dictionary, either forget about type safety (in terms of distinct fields) or get comfortable with duplicating your field type definitions for an additional `TypedDict`. I explained in my answer why there is no other way. (Aside from writing a custom plugin for your type checker of choice.)

Comment: "Python is a dynamically typed language and the typing system is a patchy and imperfect layer on top" - same applies to TypeScript, it's just built on top of JS. Python already adopted async await following TS, now it adopting types, but for some reason they trying to invent something new here instead of taking things that just works

Comment: @VladAnkudinov No, the two are not even remotely comparable. TypeScript is _compiled_ into regular JS with built-in type-checking _at compilation time_. This means it is _effectively_ statically typed, unless you opt out of it. Nothing of the sort is even planned for Python. Typing remains entirely optional and what does exist only serves _separate_ static type checkers and (usually) has no runtime effect at all. Whether that is good or bad is another debate entirely. But that is what we have right now.